# Adjust Image Size in Mobile Site

Tags: html, css, image

I am facing trouble in adjusting image size in mobile website. Unfortunately the image stretches the width of the screen. This issue comes up on blog on my website.

The blog software generates this code for images with declaration of the width/height which unfortunately I can not change. Therefore I am looking to overwrite them with CSS file.

```
<div class="leftbox">
<img src=".mysite.net/blog/media/Photo/Indian_tourists.jpg" width="400" height="267" alt="Indian tourists" title="Indian tourists" />
```

I tried using the following code to overwrite image size to fit the screen however it is not working.

I use this css code to overwrite floating image for the leftbox.

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) { 
.imgLeft { 
    float:none; 
    margin:0; 
}
```

}

This is the code to fit the image size in the screen.

```
    .leftbox img {
   height: auto !important;
   max-width: 100% !important;

}

.content img {
    width: auto!important;
     height: auto!important;
     max-width: 100%!important;
     max-height: 100%!important;

}
```

For some reason, none of these codes are working on my website - http://www.easydestination.net/blog/. See a blog through a mobile browser to understand. How can I prevent the image from stretching the screen.

Comment: Weel, remove the width and height HTML attributes first. Nearly any CMS allows this in some way (or at least by hacking the core :-)

Comment: What's `.imgLeft` class, it does not appear to exist in your HTML.

Comment: Mayank, have you adjusted the sidebar, header for the responsive design? First do that and then the images.

Comment: @odedta sorry it was typing mistake. Its acutally .leftbox

Comment: @ManojKumar I have a separate mobile design for the blog. Everything else it done. I am just stuck at images.

Comment: Are you watching these changes on your desktop or your mobile? because if you're simply resizing your browser size then that query won't work. You can change `max-device-width` to `max-width` if you're testing on your desktop. Would be better if you could create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @odedta I am viewing these changes on my android phone. I will change it to max-width and see if it works. And sorry but I don't know how to use jsfiddle.net

Comment: Simply paste all your code in the right place and hit run, the URL will change, you can post that URL here.

Comment: @odedta by all code do you mean the entire CSS file code?

Comment: @odedta I hope this is what you meant - http://jsfiddle.net/yzqkoLy5/

Comment: Okay, so you have a live link to your website, what exactly are you trying to change, which image it is?

Comment: @odedta as you can see in the jsfiddle.net, the floating image which appears in the content. This image is causing problem. It stretches the width of page beyond mobile screen.

Comment: Please check the following query: `@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) { 
 .leftbox img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
 }
}` make sure it is loaded last, let me know when you've updated it.

Comment: @odedta Please see if I got it right. I am still new to these coding stuff. http://jsfiddle.net/yzqkoLy5/2/

Comment: @MayankGupta, this is the link to your CSS file: http://www.easydestination.net/blog/skins/motoland/style.css - I don't see any media queries there... add the one I told you to into this CSS file.

Comment: @odedta Actually the css file would be easydestination.net/blog/skins/fone/style.css This is the one for mobile site, the one you looked into is desktop skin.

Comment: Well, when I view that page http://www.easydestination.net/blog/item/new-visa-rules-yet-to-affect-tourism - via mobile that CSS file doesn't seem to get loaded, all I see are `<style>` tags but no external `<link href="` tag... so that media query basically is not loaded. You have to make sure that when a viewer looks at your mobile version that style is loaded. I have no idea what kind of redirection you made to your mobile website, you have to fix that on your own I guess.

Comment: @odedta Are you talking about this? <link href="http://www.easydestination.net/blog/skins/fone/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
Because I can see it in the source code on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all you have to do is add a media query that will decrease the image size accordingly, try:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) {
    .leftbox img {
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
    }
}
```

Then you could see this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) { 
.leftbox { 
    float:none; 
    margin:0; 
}
```

This is your solution, not

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) { 
.imgLeft { 
    float:none; 
    margin:0; 
}
```

So replace .imgLeft with .leftbox and you will have what you want.

Edit:
You will still have horizontal scroll, because of footer.
Remove margin: 0 -10px; from footer, so do:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) { 
.leftbox { 
    float:none; 
    margin:0; 
} 
.footer{
margin:0;
}
```